# How to toggle a bootstrap switch with Selenium Java Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

For one of my tests, I need to press a bootstrap switch button, it has the following html:

```
<div class="bootstrap-switch-container" style="width: 93px; margin-left: -31px;">
  <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-primary" style="width: 31px;">ON</span>
  <span class="bootstrap-switch-label" style="width: 31px;">11111&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default" style="width: 31px;">OFF</span>
  <input name="form:taskDone" id="input_form:taskDone" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

I tried using

```
By TASK_DONE_SWITCH_LOCATOR = By.id("input_form:taskDone");
taskDoneSwitch = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(TASK_DONE_SWITCH_LOCATOR));
taskDoneSwitch.click();
```

Then I receive the following exception:

```
Timed out after 5 seconds
Build info: version: '2.8.0', revision: '14056', time: '2011-10-06 15:53:48'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:220)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:188)
    at hu.dual.webapp.customerservice.note.AbstractNoteTest.refreshEditPageTaskElements(AbstractNoteTest.java:161)
    at hu.dual.webapp.customerservice.note.EditNoteTest.setTaskToDone(EditNoteTest.java:76)
```

The stacktrace points to this line:

```
taskDoneSwitch = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(TASK_DONE_SWITCH_LOCATOR));
```

And then it doesn't click. How can I click it? I tried using the other fields and the ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated as well, but I still couldn't click it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` in the id attribute might cause the problem. Try to use partial id

```
By TASK_DONE_SWITCH_LOCATOR = By.cssSelector("[id*='input_form']");
```

Or

```
By TASK_DONE_SWITCH_LOCATOR = By.cssSelector("[id*='taskDone']");
```

Or both

```
By TASK_DONE_SWITCH_LOCATOR = By.cssSelector("[id*='input_form'][id*='taskDone']");
```

> Edit

You can also try clicking on the parent element

```
By.className("bootstrap-switch-container");
```

Comment: This doesn't throw any exception but doesn't click the button either! Thanks for the attention!

Comment: @brightpants Maybe you need to click on other element? like `By.className("bootstrap-switch-primary");` or `By.className("bootstrap-switch-default");`

Comment: I tried both of them, but the messages were: 

unknown error: Element <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-primary" style="width: 31px;">...</span> is not clickable at point (218, 686). Other element would receive the click: <div class="col-lg-6">...</div>

Comment: @brightpants It looks like something is covering those elements. Is it possible to get rid of it? another option is to try clicking on the parent element  `By.className("bootstrap-switch-container");`

Comment: Yesss!!!!! Clicking the parent element solved it! Thanks! Can you edit your answer with this solution or should I add mine?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by increasing the wait from 5 to 30.

If still not work try with below code :

```
WebElement taskDoneSwitch = driver.findElement(TASK_DONE_SWITCH_LOCATOR );
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", taskDoneSwitch );
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: well, 30s didn't solve it, and the code you suggested gives me this exception:

unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :